# File input output in c

Tags: c, file, input

Can some one explain me how to read content from a binary file?

I have done this:

```
FILE *fp;
int a[50];
fp=fopen("x.exe","rb");
while(fread(&a,sizeof(a),1,fp)==1)
{
    printf("%d",a);
}
```

suppose that file only contain integer values.

Also I tired writing into a file using structures, and I can easily read&write contents of it, but when I try reading some other binary file I just got garbage value.

Or is it impossible to read a `.exe` file compliled and linked?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: What is `e`?  How and where was it defined?  `sizeof` can produce unexpected results depending on what that is and how you declared it.

Comment: thats a typo, it should be a my bad

Comment: my question is can exe file readable from fread? if yes how?

Comment: The reading part of your code looks fine (except for the missing error check after `fopen`).

Comment: What do you expect when you read a binary executable file? Of course you can open and read an `.exe` file, but unless you know the binary format, all you get is garbage. I don't know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read .exe in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766523/how-to-read-exe-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct way is:

```
int myreadfile(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int i, n;
    unsigned char a[50];
    if (!(fp=fopen("x.exe","rb"))) return(0);
    while(n=fread(a,1,sizeof(a), fp))
    {
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
            printf("%02x ",a[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 1;
}
```

Note that the buffer is of type unsigned char. That is because

a) you don't know if the file is a complete number of ints (but it is of char, i.e. bytes) and

b) in the `printf` call, the `char` will be converted to `int`and would the high bit of the char be a 1, it would be sign-extended, which we don't want.

Also, `fread` does not try to read a whole buffer but just any number of bytes still in the file (to a maximum of the buffer).

Comment: yea that is what , exactly what i wanted to see .